# Attempting to seamlessly loop through undetermined amount of videos in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an undetermined amount of very short videos that I would like to loop through.

I have the following HTML:

```
<video class="bgvid bgvid--0 bgvid--visible" poster="<?= URL ;?>img/vidframe.jpg" src="1920x800.webm" playsinline muted></video>
<video class="bgvid bgvid--1 bgvid--hidden" poster="<?= URL ;?>img/vidframe.jpg" src="1920x800.2.webm" playsinline muted></video>
<video class="bgvid bgvid--2 bgvid--hidden" poster="<?= URL ;?>img/vidframe.jpg" src="1920x800.2.webm" playsinline muted></video>
```

In my CSS I show the one video with class bgvid--visible, and hide all others with class bgvid--hidden as follows:

```
.bgvid--hidden { opacity: 0; }
.bgvid--visible { opacity: 1; }
```

In my JS I start playback of my initial video by doing the following:

```
$('.bgvid--0').get(0).play();
```

Then after 5 seconds using CSS transitions and by switching the bgvid--visible and bgvid--hidden classes I "fade out" the current "active" video, and start playback and "fade in" the following video as follows:

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $('.bgvid--0').removeClass('bgvid--visible').addClass('bgvid--hidden');
        }, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
            $('.bgvid--1').get(0).play();
            $('.bgvid--1').removeClass('bgvid--hidden').addClass('bgvid--visible');
        }, 4500);
```

Notice the second timeout being slightly shorter than the first in order to create the impression of a seamless transition by fading in the next video prior to fading out the active one.

I have read about "ended" events, but the transition has to start before the video has ended. How can I turn this into a loop of some kind that loops this way through an undetermined amount of videos?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of your video using `videoElement.duration`, and the current time with `videoElement.currentTime`.

You can use the HTML Audio/Video `timeupdate` event to monitor if the current time reached the last 5 seconds, and then start the transition to the next video.

```
videoElement.ontimeupdate = function() {
    if (videoElement.currentTime >= videoElement.duration - 5) {
        startTransition();
    }
};
```

You could use only the duration, and simply set your timeout accordingly, but nothing guarantees that a 30 seconds video will *really* end 30 seconds later. It can be paused, or it can buffer for some time. But this method will tell you when the video is *really* 5 seconds from the end.